# Display different footer for jasper report summary section

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using Jasper Reports 5.5.2. I have created a report with header, detail, footer and summary sections. I want to display page header and a footer (which is different from `<pageFooter>`) in summary section.

I know that using `isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true"` will display `<pageHeader>` and `<pageFooter>` for summary section; so I am using it. But I want a different footer only for summary section. What should I do for it? (I have also tried `<lastPageFooter>` tag but it is completely irrelevant to my problem.)

**EDIT**: My summary section goes upto 2-3 pages since I am displaying HTML file content there, so I want pagination to be intact in summary section.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many pages proceed the summary section you can use the following code in the expression proerty of your footer subreport:

```
IF($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()>3,"summarySectionFooter.jasper","regularFooter.jasper")
```

3 is the number of pages that proceed the summary section. If this is a variable number you can use other code to place the right page number here.